# WordPress rest API OAuth curl commands

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, oauth

I have the [WordPress rest API](http://v2.wp-api.org)
and [WordPress OAuth server setup plugins](https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1) setup and am trying to authenticate using http://sevengoslings.net/~fangel/oauth-explorer/
every time the call content is not giving me the OAuth token or OAuth secret that I need.

I tried these steps
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/json-rest-api-from-mobile-app-with-authentication

```
1. Enter base url (http(s)://your.domain.com/oauth1
2. Access token = request
3. Authorize = authorize
4. Access_Token = access
5. Enter your consumer key and secret (leave method as HMAC-SHA1)
```

Click `Get Request Token` and you get Call content

I should get this in Call Content

```
Call content now = 

oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_token_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_call_back_confirmed=true
```

But I only get this

```
 page not found
```

Here they were not able to get 3-legged OAuth1 .0a to work so they used basic OAuth which requires another plugin and is not recommended for production.

Should I be using a different signature method?

I'm looking for two curl commands to get an OAuth grant from the server and another one to trade this grant for an access token+ refresh token.

Comment: Can you provide some code samples you already tried? Does your OAuth setup accept POST requests? Is your setup accessible for others to try?

Answer (score 5):

I have got this to work and I'll outline how I have done this.

I'm using the [Postman application](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test and perfect the API calls. I highly advise using this. Once you have got the call working you can export to PHP Curl (or whatever you need).

[If you use Postman you can view my API calls using this shared link.](https://www.getpostman.com/collections/5b912ad545c5db50d731)

For the **First call** you are having trouble with I have the following settings

First, I made sure my endpoint URL was:

```
{{url}}/oauth1/request
```

I set my API Call to PUSH and my AuthType to OAuth 1.0

I added my consumer_key and consumer_secret that I created in the WP Backend > Users > Applications (this is added with the OAuth plugin).

Signature Method - HSAC-SHA1

Then Postman will update this and dynamically create your Nonce, Timestamp and Version.

I set my Realm as 'Example'

I then made sure that I enabled the options:
- Add Params to header
- Add empty params to signature

Here is what I get for my params:

```
realm="Example",oauth_consumer_key="AdPuqyWrAQQc",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1470248765",oauth_nonce="dnOTvG",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="gUahTX2hfV1lqZCfMUvHtLLoauI%3D"
```

This provides me with the following output:

```
oauth_token=xbTb4E93K6pP2tcg4qGJIYgl&oauth_token_secret=qWo01WL2ish205yvjiU8qyCkKVPMNUvSbKpFBB1T1oOuOtBc&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

I can use Postman to export this API call to a cURL function and if so I get the following:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://mydomain.dev/oauth1/request",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_consumer_key\"\r\n\r\nAdPuqyWrAQQc\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_token\"\r\n\r\n\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_signature_method\"\r\n\r\nHMAC-SHA1\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_timestamp\"\r\n\r\n1470241356\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_nonce\"\r\n\r\n7VKp4N\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_version\"\r\n\r\n1.0\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_signature\"\r\n\r\n9qRrIkDxt56S9Ikf061eFOVLAdA%3D\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: OAuth realm=\"Example\",oauth_consumer_key=\"AdPuqyWrAQQc\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1470248765\",oauth_nonce=\"dnOTvG\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"gUahTX2hfV1lqZCfMUvHtLLoauI%3D\"",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001",
    "postman-token: dd85258e-a72a-b731-82d1-00109e30962f"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo 'response ' . $response;

  $a = parse_str($response);

  echo 'token ' . $oauth_token;
  echo '<br>';
  echo 'secret '. $oauth_token_secret;


}
```

This is step 1 of a 3 step process for OAuth Authentication. I'm just starting out on my journey to connect them all. There is not much documentation out there and not many examples.

Step 2 looks like a call to /oauth1/authorize with the provided token and secret. This looks like it then requires a user login and a new (and permenant) token and secret is created.

Step 3 looks like a call to /oauth1/access

**I haven't succesfully got Step 2 and Step 3 to link together correctly, but I thought I should post to help with the original query about the first step not returning the correct tokens**

[This article](https://www.sitepoint.com/wp-api-and-oauth-using-wordpress-without-wordpress/) is one of the better ones out there explaining how to use WP-API and OAuth.